# Multiple Argument Types for HTTpPost Method in ASP.NET MVC Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page on which I want to show information in two sets :

```
<div id="DivMainContainer">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Settings</legend>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Settings", null))
    {
        <table id="TableMain" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50%;vertical-align:top">
                @*@Html.Partial("_TableColumnNames")*@
                  @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model=>model.PostedColumns.ColumnIds,
        model=>model.AllColumns,
        columnItem=>columnItem.Id,
        columnItem=>columnItem.ColumnName,
        model=>model.SelectedColumns,
        Position.Vertical)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table id="TableGridSettings">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="FirstCell">
                                #Records per page
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="FirstCell">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="FirstCell">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="FirstCell">
                                <label id="LabelGridRowCount" for="InputGridRowCount">
                                    Snapshot Grids</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="InputGridRowCountSG" name="InputGridRowCount" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="FirstCell">
                                Data Sets Grid
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="InputGridRowCountDST" name="InputGridRowCountDST" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="FirstCell">
                                Data Sources Grid
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="InputGridRowCountDSR" name="InputGridRowCountDSR" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="FirstCell">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button>
            Save</button>
    }
</fieldset>
```

The first cell in this table contains a strongly typed (model-bound) CheckBoxList and the second cell contains three simple text fields to capture information.

There is a save button which will cause a post to this method below :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PostedColumns postedColumns) 
   {
        try
        {
            return View(GetColumnsModel(postedColumns));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
        return View();
    }
```

The Post method accepts argument of type "PostedColumns" since that is the type of the information posted by the CheckBoxList helper I am using.

Now I also want to collect information from the other three simple controls and that can be done using FormCollection if the post method was revised as below :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
   {
        try
        {
           //do something like form["txtInputId"]......to read values
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
        return View();
    }
```

But this means I am not able to now get the posted info from checkboxlist.

Looking for some pointers on how to capture/post info from both these controls when the save is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Venkat indicated, creating a view model is your best option but you can also add additional parameters to your POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PostedColumns postedColumns, string InputGridRowCount, string InputGridRowCountDST, string InputGridRowCountDSR)
{
  ...
```

or your could manually get the values from `Request.Form`

```
public ActionResult Index(PostedColumns postedColumns)
{
  string inputGridRowCount = Request.Form["InputGridRowCount"];
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the other simple fields into the same model itself so that you will be able to get the value from the same model itself on post back. Or else create a new wrapper class as a model which will hold the PostedColumns and the properties related to the other controls.
Then bind this model to the View you are using. Then change the post action method with the new model that is created and can get the value from the view model. If you provide the whole view and model it will be easy to check for the solution in much better way.